# How to retrieve only deleted contacts using Google Contacts API?

Tags: javascript, json, api, filter, google-contacts-api

I want to retrieve **only** deleted contacts with a lower bound of time.

I already tried these filters in query string:

```
updated-min=2016-02-08T11:17:47.559Z&deleted=true

updated-min=2016-02-08T11:17:47.559Z&showdeleted=true&deleted=true
```

Results include both deleted=true and deleted=false

Comment: Both links are dead (404 Error)

Comment: @Athafoud just showing what calls i already tried, actually you need to pass headers with calls

Comment: Consider to edit your question, in order to make it more clear.